# How do return "null" instead of a dummy instance of my generic type (class)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a custom **SerializableDictionary** where I can put any struct or class for both key and value. My problem is that when I return a "default" of when the key or value are a class, I get a dummy instance with default properties, instead of null.

I wish to either return null when the "default" is from a class type, or define each class type that for it, "default" means null.

I am aware of the Nullable fix for structs, but that requires me specify that the types be "where key/value is struct" and it blocks class types from being used.

Anybody got any help?
P.S: search for "//HERE IS THE ISSUE!"

```
    [Serializable]
    public class SerializableDictionary<TKeyType, TValueType> : ISerializableDictionary
    {
        [SerializeField]
        protected List<TKeyType> keys = new List<TKeyType>();

        [SerializeField]
        protected List<TValueType> values = new List<TValueType>();

        public void CloneFrom( SerializableDictionary<TKeyType, TValueType> source )
        {
            keys   = source.keys.Clone();
            values = source.values.Clone();
        }

        public SerializableDictionary<TKeyType, TValueType> Clone()
        {
            SerializableDictionary<TKeyType, TValueType> result = new SerializableDictionary<TKeyType, TValueType>();
            result.CloneFrom( this );

            return result;
        }

        public void SetValue( TKeyType key, TValueType value )
        {
            int index = keys.IndexOf( key );

            if( index != -1 )
            {
                values[ index ] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                keys.Add( key );
                values.Add( value );
            }
        }

        public bool hasValue( TValueType value ) => values.Contains( value );

        public bool hasEntry( TKeyType key ) => keys.Contains( key );

        public void remove( TValueType value )
        {
            int index = values.IndexOf( value );

            if( index == -1 )
            {
                return;
            }

            keys.RemoveAt( index );
            values.RemoveAt( index );
        }
        public void remove( TKeyType key )
        {
            int index = keys.IndexOf( key );

            if( index == -1 )
            {
                return;
            }

            keys.RemoveAt( index );
            values.RemoveAt( index );
        }

        //HERE IS THE ISSUE!
        public TValueType getValueFromKey( TKeyType key )
        {
            int index = keys.IndexOf( key );

            return index != -1 ? values[ index ] : default;
        }

        //HERE IS THE ISSUE!
        public TKeyType getKeyFromValue( TValueType value )
        {
            int index = values.IndexOf( value );

            return index != -1 ? keys[ index ] : default;
        }

        public List<TValueType> GetValues()
        {
            return values.ToList();
        }

        public List<TKeyType> GetKeys()
        {
            return keys.ToList();
        }

        public SerializableDictionary<TKeyType, TFilter> filterByType<TFilter>() where TFilter : TValueType
        {
            SerializableDictionary<TKeyType, TFilter> result = new SerializableDictionary<TKeyType, TFilter>();

            for( int index = 0; index < values.Count; index++ )
            {
                if( values[ index ] is TFilter )
                {
                    result.SetValue( keys[index], (TFilter) values[index] );
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        public int Count => keys.Count;

        //public object Current => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void Clear()
        {
            keys.Clear();
            values.Clear();
        }

        [Obsolete]
        public string GetFieldAsString( int iterator )
        {
            return Count <= iterator ? null : keys[ iterator ].ToString();
        }

        [Obsolete]
        public string GetValueAsString( int iterator )
        {
            return Count <= iterator ? null : values[ iterator ].ToString();
        }

        private TValueType getValueAt( int iterator )
        {
            return Count <= iterator ? default : values[ iterator ];
        }
        /*
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            IEnumerator a;
            a.
        }*/
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that `default` for a class gives you an instance, not `null`?

Comment: Yes Lasse :/ I assume because the class type is serializable.

Comment: **Are** you serializing/deserializing this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the calling code where you're getting a dummy instance instead of null?

Comment: I have never used default; did you try default(TValueType); ?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Nope, I removed it now and still it behaves like that, so not the issue.

Comment: @JohnM.Wright I call getValueFromKey, that's it.

Comment: @NthDeveloper It is the same thing, the new .net version allows the shorthand

Comment: What types are you using in your current example where you have problems, ie. what is the exact type of TValueType and TKeyType, and can you show their declarations?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Almost always either string + simple class with primitives (my current issue), or simple primitive + MonoBehavior

Comment: The code provided doesn't compile.
1) Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'ISerializableDictionary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2) Error CS1061 'List<TValueType>' does not contain a definition for 'Clone' (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3) Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'SerializeField' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You don't need to compile it. And if, for some reason, you do, delete those things. Simple Unity C# code, really.

Comment: The problem is that your code works. It doesn't return a dummy object, all attempts we make at reproducing, and thus understanding, your problem is met with a failure. There **has** to be something missing from your code. You **must** provide a [mcve] or nobody here can help you.

Answer (score -1):

I can't reproduce it. I tested the code with strings as values, and after deserialization the values are preserved as they should:

```
var dict = new SerializableDictionary<int, string>();
dict.SetValue(1, default);
dict.SetValue(2, "");
dict.SetValue(3, "Andromeda");
var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var stream = new MemoryStream();
binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, dict);
stream.Position = 0;
dict = (SerializableDictionary<int, string>)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
foreach (var key in dict.GetKeys())
{
    var value = dict.getValueFromKey(key);
    Console.Write($"Key: {key}, Value: ");
    if (value == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("null");
    }
    else if (value == String.Empty)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("String.Empty");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\"{value}\"");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Key: 1, Value: null
Key: 2, Value: String.Empty
Key: 3, Value: "Andromeda"
```

**Remarks:** For the class `SerializableDictionary` to compile, I had to comment out the following lines of code.

```
//: ISerializableDictionary
//[SerializeField]
//[SerializeField]
//keys = source.keys.Clone();
//values = source.values.Clone();
```

Comment: Try a class that is serialized and use it for either key or value. Two primitives like int and string aren't my use case.

Comment: @Discipol I would suggest that you show us your use case, by providing a reproducible example that we can copy-paste and compile, instead of trying in vain to reproduce it by trial and error. Please help us so that we can help you! 

Comment: Pfff, I tried! As you saw, there's some extra stuff that I have to break away from the big project. A part "fix" is to make a tryGet instead of get and if I return "false", then I use "null" instead of the default dummy object. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @Discipol then the problem should be hidding somewhere in that extra stuff you omitted, because your class as is works fine! As a side note, you should take a look at [C# Capitalization Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions). Public members of a class, and especially methods, are expected to be capitalized with PascalCasing. Use camelCasing for local variables, method arguments and private fields only.